# Remove the word chapter but keeping the numbering

Tags: markdown

I wanted to remove the word chapter when I do `\chapter{title}` I added the command 1, but I do not have anymore the numbering, I added the command 2 but when I do `\ chapter*{Intro}` he puts me **0. Intro**

**Main.Rmd**

```
---
documentclass: report
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preambule.tex
  word_document: default
subparagraph: yes
---

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Intro}

\chapter{Title}
```

**preambule.tex**

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge} **command 1**
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\ } **command 2**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the instruction

```
\let\chaptername\relax
```

in the preamble. `\renewcommand\chaptername{}` works too.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{report}
\let\chaptername\relax
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Intro}
bla bla bla

\chapter{Title}
more bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, i have this now: line 1:  1, line 2: title

Comment: @problème0123 - The first sentence in your query is, "I wanted to remove the word chapter". That's exactly what my answer achieves, isn't it? However, if removing the word "Chapter" is *not* what you wish to achieve, please clarify what the real objective is.